# node.js rendered page not loading styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

That's my first-day learning Node.js and on making a basic server that basically renders 1 page containing a header tag, I get an error saying that the CSS file can't be loaded

That's my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const HOST = '127.0.0.1';
const PORT = 3000;

const app = express();

//app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "static")));
app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "static", 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT, HOST, () => {
    console.log(`Running Server on ${HOST}:${PORT}`)
});
```

The HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World From Node.js!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The Error:
[image]

File Tree:

[image]

I just want to be pointed at the missing part here for the css file to be linked with the HTML

> Note: the CSS file is loaded when I directly run the HTML by browser

Comment: You're only serving your html file on `/`, express doesn't magically serve other files or paths you didn't specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `express.static()` (that you commented out) to serve static files.

According to [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) you need

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "static")));
```

This way CSS should load. Any request like `http://127.0.0.1:3000/css/index.css` will be checked against `static` directory and if matching file is found Express will serve it.

If request does not match the file in that directory (for example `http://127.0.0.1:3000/`) Express will continue to look for other matching routes and will execute `app.get('/', fn)` because it'll match.

For reference, full code:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const HOST = '127.0.0.1';
const PORT = 3000;

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "static")));
app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "static", 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT, HOST, () => {
    console.log(`Running Server on ${HOST}:${PORT}`)
});
```

**UPDATED** There are two ways to use `express.static()` as [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) explain:

When calling `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "static")));` (without a prefix specified) `index.css` file, for example, will be available at

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/css/index.css
```

When calling `app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "static")));` (with `/public` prefix) the same `index.css` file will be available under `/public` prefix at

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/public/css/index.css
```

This approach counter-intuitive because `index.html` needs to be updated to load CSS from this prefix (and will only work when loaded via http://127.0.0.1:3000/, not when opened as a local file):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./public/css/index.css">
```

Comment: Actually, I commented it to check if that changes anything, when I uncomment it the same happens, but when I modified that line to remove "/public" as you did it worked

Comment: there are two ways to use `express.static()`, please see docs link. I'm suggesting using `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "static")));` while you previously had `app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "static")));`, there is big difference in the way which URLs will correspond to files.

Comment: I was about to ask you about the difference, but never mind I will check the docs you linked, thanks for help

Comment: I've added an example of using those two forms.

Comment: I can say that was a perfect answer, Thank you so much for making time to help me

Answer (score 0):

you can load the static assets by creating a virtual path like

```
app.use('/assets',express.static(__dirname + '/public/css'));
```

where the public is the directory where all your assets are stored,in which CSS is the folder where is all your CSS file are stored , you can you the virtual path in the link tag , href attribute for loading the css ,eg: if you have template file ,you write in it ,the link tag  i have tried with the same directory structure like yours and tried to emulate the bug and fixed the css load issue you can refer : https://github.com/ardnahcivar/Node.js-Code-/tree/master/11-17-18 the code

Comment: using the virtual path defined in use() method was actually the bug I had as I used my real path in the HTML file which in my case /static/css , but I get it now, thanks for help